What statistical tests to use for multiple datasets?
I have calculated the species richness of mammals in 10 sites, for different variables. For example, I have the species richness of carnivores, omnivores, herbivores etc in one analysis group, and whether they are tolerant of human disturbance or not in a separate group. I want to compare these to the rates of deforestation in the different sites, which I have measured by counting the pixels of deforested area in the past 20 years from satellite imagery. Could anyone tell me what kind of data analysis I need to do to test for significance? Any help would be really appreciated.

I was thinking that the species richness for each animal guild would be the dependent variable because it is (theoretically) being influenced by the forest cover loss, but I could be wrong?

What do you want to find out? What are your hypotheses and research questions? Also, is species richness a continuous variable?

Sorry, I accidentally deleted my original comment. Yes, that sounds reasonable. So you have species richness and deforestation in both datasets, but species categorization as omnivores etc. only in one, and species categorization by tolerance only in other? And you'd like to combine the two datasets?

I want to find out if there is a correlation between forest cover loss and the species richness of different animal groups. For example, an individual animal can be in the carnivore and terrestrial groups simultaneously, while another can be a herbivore and terrestrial. As an example, I want to see if the factor of the animals diet is more or less significant than their preferred movement.

How is species richness measured? Do you have one value of richness for each of the 10 sites, or do you have several individual animal observations from each site, and richness is somehow computed on the basis of these individual animal observations?

I've measured the number of sightings and not the species richness, but I can fix that to actually show species richness. I did this for each diet type, locomotion type and tolerance type, and I want to see if I can compare the relationships between the different variables, eg whether deforestation affects carnivorous terrestrial mammals more than herbivorous flying ones.

So you data is something like this/could be arranged like this?
site  diet   locomotion  tolerance  sightings  deforestation
A     omni   terr             yes   35         10
A     carni  terr             yes   20         10
A     herbi  terr             yes   24         10
A     omni   fly              yes   15         10
A     carni  fly              yes   28         10
A     herbi  fly              yes   40         10
A     omni   terr             no    55         10
A     carni  terr             no    10         10
A     herbi  terr             no    22         10
A     omni   fly              no    32         10
A     carni  fly              no    12         10
A     herbi  fly              no    45         10
B     omni   terr             yes   30         20
B     carni  terr             yes   5          20
... etc.
# where sighting denotes the count of sightings (e.g. first sighting number of 35 would mean there were 35 observations of terrestial tolerant omnivores at site A)

If so, and the count of sightings can be seen as indicator of species richness, a multilevel poisson regression predicting sightings from other attributes, with a random intercept of site, or a single-level poisson regression with standard errors clustered by site might work.
EDIT. the last paragraph means that you need some way to control for the fact that your observations are clustered within sites and observations from same sites are likely to be related with each other more than observations from different sites. In other words, your observations are not independent.
I'll show a crude example of a multilevel Poisson model, but you probably need to do some reading of both multilevel models and poisson models if you want to use this approach (they are not difficult to use but there are some details that are a bit complex).
For instance in R a model like this might work:
library(lme4)
model<-glmer(sightings ~ diet + locomotion + tolerance + deforestation + (1|site), data = yourdata, family="poisson")
summary(model)

^This gives you the main effects of each predictor. If you want to know whether, for instance, deforestation has a different effect on richness depending on diet, you'd need to put in interaction terms, e.g. deforestation * diet
In the above model code, the (1|site) is a random intercept of site, which takes into account the fact that your sightings are clustered within sites and not independent as assumed in a regular regression. If you'd just run a regular regression with data like this, your standard errors might be artificially small. To further illustrate, if your observations were all from the same site (or each and every one of them was from a different and independent site), you could just run a regular poisson model of
model<-glm(sightings ~ diet + locomotion + tolerance + deforestation, data=data, family="poisson")

And I suggested poisson regression because your outcome seems to be counts, in which case poisson is a typical choice. This has nothing to do with the clustering within sites, that's a separate issue.

That looks like it could be perfect for what I need, thank you so much. I am a little confused with what you mean by "predicting sightings from other attributes, with a random intercept of site", and "standard errors clustered by site" are these factors I need to add to the analysis separate from the data I already have?

I'll edit in further info!

A very helpful answer.  Crystal-clear.

Thank you so much, this helps a lot!
